# How to override bootstrap datable css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have modified my datatable to be editable but I ran into a display problem and it looked like below:
[image]

I played around in firefox's inspector changing some css settings and fixed the issue so now it looks like this.

[image]

What I modified is this block of css it was `class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"`, I modified it so that it's just `class="col-sm-12 col-md`.

[image]
[image]

Now how can I make my css changes permanent for this table only? ps, I know the tags say boostrap-4 but I'm actually using boostrap-5. Couldn't find it in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an important tag like this to your main css stylesheet to override your bootstrap.

```
.col-sm-12{width:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the head section of your html place your custom.css below bootstrap.css to override the styling

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap demo</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```